# Doctrine is not loading or saving a specific attribute in my entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

this problem has been driving me nuts for the past few hours. I added the attribute **posts_published_date** to my **user** entity (it tracks the date a specific user made a post last). Here are some relevant lines:

Initializing the attributes in the entity.

```
/**
 * @Column(type="integer", length=3, nullable=false)
 */
protected $posts_published_today;
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=7, nullable=true)
 */
protected $posts_published_date;
/**
 * @Column(type="integer", length=3, nullable=true)
 */
protected $posts_published_limit;
```

Using the attributes in the entity:

```
public function setPostsPublishedToday($value){
    $today = date("now");
    if ($today != $this->posts_published_date){
        $this->posts_published_today = 1;
        debug($this->posts_published_date . " != " . $today, "1");
        $this->posts_published_date  = $today;
        debug($this->posts_published_date . " == " . $today, "2");
    } else {
        $this->posts_published_today = $value;
    }
}
```

The two debugs run with the following output:

```
Debug 1: != 220136
Debug 2: 220136 == 220136
```

The **posts_published_date** does not get stored in the database, but **posts_published_today** is being retrieved and stored fine.

Comment: You should add the code that you use in this case.

Also, consider using a `"datetime"` field type for the `posts_published_date` property, and then assigning a `DateTime` object to it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use that class variable's setter function, instead of accessing it directly? Try:

```
public function setPostsPublishedToday($value)
{
   $today = date("now");
   if ($today != $this->getPostsPublishedDate()) {
      $this->posts_published_today = 1;
      $this->setPostsPublishedDate($today);
   } else {
      $this->posts_published_today = $value;
   }
}
```

That way everything is routed through base methods that you can guarantee behaviour of. If you allow your code access to class variables it becomes uncontaintable and a nightmare to debug if you happen to change a particular DB column, etc. What happens when you try the above? Are you persisting everything?

Comment: He is working within the entity itself... I wouldn't worry about using the public API in such a context, but that is always a big discussion in OOP :)

Comment: Yes, I'm within the entity itself. your suggested change had no effect. What happens is that the posts_published_today is succesfully changed (I checked in phpMyAdmin), while the posts_published_date stays as whatever it was before. This tells me that the persist and the flush are working properly.